# iOS Keyboard cover some UITextField in static tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

There are a few UITextField in a cell of my static UITableView. Most of them are fine when get focus.

[image]

[image]

But when some of the fields get focus (when I click for example the Unit No field), the cell jumps and will be covered keyboard like this.

[image]

Totally got no clue. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Finally find the reason. It will cause this issue if one cell height more the the screen height.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this pod https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager, It will cover all keyboard scenario.

If you want to use custom code you have to subscribe for **UIKeyboardWillShow** and **UIKeyboardWillHide** in **viewWillAppear**, and unsubscribe in **viewWillDisappear**. After that override **touchesBegan** this will handle your all touches on the screen, you can endEditing in this function.

My Sample code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
  if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
      UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.view.bounds.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
      }
  }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.bounds.origin.y = 0
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: This is good library. But doesn't solve my problem. The keyboard still cover the field when I move to certain fields.

Comment: If you are using IQKeyboard Manager, In viewWillAppear, call super.viewWillAppear, not calling superView causes such problem in IQKeyboard Manager

Comment: Still the same. Some UITextField with focus still be blocked by the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IQKeybordManager POD. It manages everything automatically.